# linux sleeping with clock_nanosleep

Tags: c++, sleep, clock

I want to use clock_nanosleep for waiting of 1 microsec.. As far as I understand, I have to give an absolute time as input. Is the following code okay in this case?

```
deadline.tv_sec = 0;
deadline.tv_nsec = 1000;

clock_nanosleep(CLOCK_REALTIME, TIMER_ABSTIME, &deadline, NULL);
```

Comment: what does the manpage say, and when you tried it, what did you observe?

Comment: It says I have to use TIMER_ABSTIME in order to set absolute time. However, it seems there is something wrong with my implementation.

Comment: I am pretty sure that here more than a microsecond has passed since the epoch, but since you haven't mentioned why it seems that something is wrong with your implementation, it might be different at your location.

Comment: @AvbAvb: You can use `TIMER_ABSTIME` to set absolute time, or `0` to set relative time. It looks like you want to do the latter.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> As far as I understand, I have to give an absolute time as input.

No, the `flags` argument allows you to choose relative or absolute time. You want

```
clock_nanosleep(CLOCK_REALTIME, 0, &deadline, NULL);
```

to specify one microsecond from now.

Comment: It worked! Do you know whether I get the same performance if I use usleep(1) instead.

Comment: @AvbAvb: No idea, you'll have to measure it. But if performance is an issue, then why are you sleeping?

Comment: Perhaps performance is the wrong wording. I should have say better accuracy in terms of sleeping time.

Comment: `usleep()` is obsolete... Why would you want to use that?

Answer (score 28):

Your deadline tv is not an absolute time.  To form an absolute time, get the current time with  `clock_gettime()` (http://linux.die.net/man/3/clock_gettime), then add your sleep interval.

```
struct timespec deadline;
clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &deadline);

// Add the time you want to sleep
deadline.tv_nsec += 1000;

// Normalize the time to account for the second boundary
if(deadline.tv_nsec >= 1000000000) {
    deadline.tv_nsec -= 1000000000;
    deadline.tv_sec++;
}
clock_nanosleep(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, TIMER_ABSTIME, &deadline, NULL);
```

Note that I'm using CLOCK_MONOTONIC instead of CLOCK_REALTIME.  You don't actually care what time it is, you just want the clock to be consistent.

Comment: Why would you do all that, rather than just requesting relative time?

Comment: Good point.  Only if you're worried about signals, in which case you still have to handle the early return yourself, or if you want to sleep for repeated intervals and minimize drift, in which case you'd compute the new deadline from the previous deadline rather than from the current time.

Comment: @MikeSeymour, I needed this because I'm devising a thread that runs periodically to test a scheduling algorithm. So, I cannot use relative times because that will accumulate error. So this could be one such application.

Comment: it is really good. if normalization code can handle the case that now.tv_nsec +  nanos_you_want_it_to_sleep >= 2 seconds, it would be perfect.

Comment: @DAG This can only happen if you add more than 1 second.  To do that in the above sample, add the whole seconds to the tv_sec field and the fractional seconds to the tv_nsec field (as done above).  Then the normalization above will work fine.  Beware overflows if you are using nanos to represent many whole seconds... in some implementations, tv_nsec will overflow at just over 2 seconds.

Answer (score 4):

@ryanyuyu

sample code::

```
void mysleep_ms(int milisec)
{
    struct timespec res;
    res.tv_sec = milisec/1000;
    res.tv_nsec = (milisec*1000000) % 1000000000;
    clock_nanosleep(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, 0, &res, NULL);
}
```

this is monotonic clock based sleep function.
please refer it.

Answer (score 1):

The most precise way to pause a program for a single microsecond (1us) is busy-waiting, `sleep` mechanism (nanosleep or clock_nanosleep) will involve task scheduling and context switch, whose latencies are greater than 1us.

Reference:

[delays - Information on the various kernel delay / sleep mechanisms](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/timers/timers-howto.html)

Answer (score 0):

I recommend 2nd way of use sleep function.
because , most of system function uses CLOCK_REALTIME, But, It has some serious problem,
If system time and date has changed.
In most case I recommend relative sleep way , best choice is using clock_monotonic.

Comment: Can you elaborate on this some more?  Maybe provide example code?